# Same view showed twice

Tags: caliburn, caliburn.micro

I would like to implement a "Module Switcher" in my application, which brings up an alt-tab like interface showing the open modules.

Right now it is structured like this

```
                ModuleShellView
                ModuleSwitcherView
         Module 1    Module 2    Module 3
```

ModuleSwitcherView is opened as a dialog from ModuleShellView and binds to the currently open Modules.

This causes the active module in the screen behind to transition to nothing. Is there a way to keep the view open in the background, while displaying it in another dialog? The alt-tab window only needs a "view" of the view, it doesn't need to be interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this. Rather than show the contentcontrol, I am grabbing the view instance, writing it to a WriteableBitmap and then using that.